# Load to Ida binary with all of SO

Tags: ida, linux, ida-plugin, shared-object

I have a Linux ARM binary with a lot of shared libraries.

Can I load all of them into one IDA instance so that I can easily navigate between functions? For example: functions that the binary calls and is implemented in one of the shared libraries.

Comment: Which version of IDA you are using?

Comment: You can simply use `File` -> `Load File` -> `Additional binary file ...`, but I haven't ever done it for your target, so possible there are issues I am unaware of.

Comment: @ViktorWolf Ida Pro 7.7

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest running your binary, attach it using IDA debug server, then take memory snapshot.

Comment: Fair point, but not viable with malware or other potentially malicious code, for example.